# Angular 6 : date disapear on refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, angular6

I have textarea which allow user to submit comments, I want to grab the date on time the comment is submitted, and save to json together with comment added.

Unfortunatelly when I submit the comment , comment and date displays as expected, but when I refresh the page date is gone .

**Note am using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)**

after comment is submitted in json file I would like to have something like this:

```
"comment": [
    {
  "id": 1,
  "localTime": "2018-10-27T13:42:55",
  "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et lig\n"
}
]
```

Problem: Right now when comment is submitted I have the following in json server,

```
 "comment": [
     {
  "id": 1,
  "localTime": null,
  "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et lig\n"
}
```

]

Here is what I have tried so far to grab the date from entered comment.

HTML :

```
<form class="add-comments" [formGroup]="addForm" (keyup.enter)="addComments()">
      <input type="hidden" id="localTime" name="localTime">
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="Add comments" formControlName="description" id="description"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Here is method on compoents ts.

```
  addComments(task_id) {
    const formData = this.addForm.value;
    formData.task_id = task_id;
    this.userService.addComments(formData)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.comments.push(this.addForm.value);
    });
    const date = new Date();
    const d = date.getUTCDate();
    const day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
    const m = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    const month = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
    const year = date.getUTCFullYear();
    const h = date.getUTCHours();
    const hour = (h < 10) ? '0' + h : h;
    const mi = date.getUTCMinutes();
    const minute = (mi < 10) ? '0' + mi : mi;
    const sc = date.getUTCSeconds();
    const second = (sc < 10) ? '0' + sc : sc;
    const loctime = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}`;

    this. addForm.get('localTime').setValue(loctime);

  }
```

Here is service for adding comments to server

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Status } from '../model/statuses.model';
import { Comment } from '../model/comments.model';
import { User } from '../model/user.model';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  status: Status[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  statusUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/statuses';
  commentsUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/comment';
  usersUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/users';

  addComments(comments: Comment) {
    return this.http.post(this.commentsUrl, comments);
  }
  getComments(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<Comment[]>(this.commentsUrl);
  }


}
```

Here is class model

```
export class Comment {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    email: string;
    days: number;
    localTime: Date;
    description: string;
}
```

what do I need to change to get what I want??

Comment: Your data will be cleared on refresh. You can try and use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to achieve your purpose.

Comment: why session storage while am using json server????

Comment: ugh, why are you trusting the *client* to send your *server* the correct date ?

Comment: @Stavm is that qn for me or @sarthank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line in your code...

```
const date = new Date();
```

... the date variable will already contain the current date and time. Instead of your custom function calls for constructing the date string, you might as well just assign this date to your comment instance before posting it to the server - as your comment will be serialized to a JSON the date attribute will automatically be converted to a date string conforming to the format you desire: `"2018-10-27T13:42:55"`.

You could just move above date assignment into your addComments method instead:

```
addComments(comments: Comment) {
  comments.localTime = new Date();
  return this.http.post(this.commentsUrl, comments);
}
```

Comment: let me check I will be back

Comment: I changed as per your answer but I get the following error : `Failed to compile.

src/app/service/user.service.ts(27,5): error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Date'.`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while adjusting the code. It should be `new Date()`, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage.

```
// Set localStorage   
localStorage.setItem('nameOfYourKey','data you will save');
// Retrieve data from
 localStorage.getItem('nameofYourKey');
```

Comment: Hii Thank u for suggestion but I dont want use local storage